# SQL - for any given date record, select the date of the record prior

Tags: sql, netezza

I have a table with customer and day_id.  For every row, I want to create a new column to show the customer's last visited date prior to the date on that particular row. I want to retain every row from my data table and have 'NULL' if there was no prior day_id for that customer.  example:

**Data Table:**
`customer    day_id

123         20180101
123         20190101
123         20180530
123         20181231
222         20180701
222         20180801`

**Desired Result:**
`customer    day_id    day_id_prior

123         20180101     NULL
123         20190101     20181231
123         20180530     20180101
123         20181231     20180530
222         20180701     NULL
222         20180801     20180701`

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Provide some data for your question, show SQL you have tried so far, problems you've encountered. Help community to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`lag`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSULQD_7.2.1/com.ibm.nz.dbu.doc/c_dbuser_lag_lead_family_syntax.html) window function.

```
select t.*,lag(day_id) over(partition by customer order by day_id) as prev_dayid
from tbl t
```